# envio de email por smtp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

Fiz uma classe que tem o seguinte código para enviar um email:

```
try
        {
            WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
            WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
            WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
            WebMail.UserName = "meuemail";
            WebMail.Password = "minhasenha";
            WebMail.From = "blabla@site.com";

            WebMail.Send("participantes@examples.com", "Notificação",
                Model.Nome + " é " + ((Model.VaiParticipar ?? false) ? "" : "Não") + "Sim");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           @:<b>Desculpe, Email não enviado</b>
        }
```

Está faltando mais alguma coisa ? Está sempre caindo no `catch`, o email não é enviado.

Comment: Por um acaso este código fica em *View*? Por que você não lança a exceção para ver a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Desalex, quando utilizei o IIS virtual/local, executando via debug/localmente, nunca enviava e-mail (mensagem de retorno: Failed to connect server). Subi minha aplicação para o host, de lá o e-mail ia perfeitamente. Via debug/localmente nunca consegui enviar. Pode ser alguma config do IIS, mas não cheguei a verificar.

Comment: a exceção é essa: System.Net.WebException: Impossível conectar-se ao servidor remoto ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não respondeu corretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou porque o host conectado não respondeu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Você deve trocar a porta (SmtpPort) de 25 para 587.**

O Comitê Gestor da Internet no Brasil (CGI.br) determinou que a partir do dia 1º de janeiro de 2013, todos os provedores de acesso e empresas de telefonia não permitam mais o envio de e-mails através da porta 25.

Isto significa que todos os usuários que utilizam clientes de e-mails como Outlook, Windows Mail, Thunderbird ou Apple mail entre outros devem trocar sua a porta SMTP de 25 para 587. Esta prática tem o intuito de diminuir o tráfego de spam no Brasil e consequentemente a uma melhora da reputação dos IPs do Brasil em CBL(lista de bloqueio que agrega endereços IP que comprovadamente enviaram spam).

Sugiro que você leia um artigo interessante sobre uma forma mais simples de escrever sua classe de envio de emails em http://www.omniscode.com.br/2015/11/19/cascade-lambda-pattern/

Comment: Obrigado, era a porta mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Mude seu fonte para capturar a mensagem de erro e entendermos onde é que está o problema conforme a modificação abaixo, outra coisa, cheque a configuração de porta e ssl, pois pelo que tenho utilizado, raramente há servidores de saída usando a porta 25 hoje em dia:

```
    }
    catch (Exception **erro**)
    {
       @:<b>Desculpe, Email não enviado</b> @:erro.Message
    }
```

Comment: Se eu passo erro.Message ele só me retorna Falha ao enviar email, se eu passo somente erro ai me retorna o erro:System.Net.WebException: Impossível conectar-se ao servidor remoto ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não respondeu corretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou porque o host conectado não respondeu

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar esta função pronta que eu utilizo e não dá erro, só se for problema do seu usuário.

```
    public class EmailServerAccount
    {
        public string EmailOrigem { get; set; }
        public string NomeOrigem { get; set; }
        public string Server { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Pass { get; set; }
        public string Retorno { get; set; }
        public Boolean Autentica { get; set; }

    }

    public static string EnviarMensagem(EmailServerAccount conta, string[] destino, string[] emailcc, string mensagem, string titulo, string anexo)
    {
        string para = destino[0];

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(para)) 
        {
            return "Erro sem e-mail ! Assunto:" + titulo;
        }

        if (conta == null)
            return "Erro, conta de e-mail não existente !";

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(conta.EmailOrigem, conta.NomeOrigem);
        message.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(conta.Retorno));

        string[] emaildestino = para.Split(';');
        //Destinatário
        foreach (string vEmailP in emaildestino)
        {
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(vEmailP));
        }

        // message.To.Add(new MailAddress(""));

        //prioridade do email
        message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        //utilize true pra ativar html no conteúdo do email, ou false, para somente texto
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        //Assunto do email
        message.Subject = titulo;

        //corpo do email a ser enviado
        message.Body = mensagem;

        // Envia a mensagem
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(conta.Server, conta.Port);

        Boolean ssl = conta.Autentica;
        client.EnableSsl = ssl;

        // Insere as credenciais se o Servidor SMTP exigir
        ///  client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        //endereço do servidor SMTP(para mais detalhes leia abaixo do código)
        client.Host = conta.Server;

        //para envio de email autenticado, coloque login e senha de seu servidor de email
        //para detalhes leia abaixo do código
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(conta.EmailOrigem, conta.Pass);

        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
            return "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return " Erro no envio de email para !  " + para + "\r\n" + " " + ex.Message + "      -       " + ex.StackTrace + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```